# How to display additional fields about the M2M field in Django or override select2-results__option

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I am looking to implement a feature to allow users to select other users and add them to their many-to-many field. The current state works in what I want it to do, but I want to be able to display additional information about the user they are selecting, and not just their username. Things like `first_name`, `last_name`, profile information, etc. - Ideally it would all be in the one line they see when adding the user to their m2m queue, such as:

`John Smith | j.smith | j.smith@example.com`

as opposed to:

`j.smith`

I see the element `select2-results__option` and I'm curious if I can just override it with the additional information. If there is a clean way to do it through django, I'd prefer to do it that way, but open to anything really.

Views.py

```
class UserAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return User.objects.none()
        qs = User.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(username__icontains=self.q) |
                           Q(first_name__icontains=self.q) |
                           Q(last_name__icontains=self.q))

        return qs
```

forms.py

```
class UserSurveyQueueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['queue'].queryset = User.objects.all().exclude(pk=user)
        self.fields['queue'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = UserSurveyQueue
        fields = ('queue',)
        widgets = {
            'queue': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                url='user-autocomplete',
            ),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light), you can override the `get_result_label` method of your `UserAutocomplete` class to change the text shown in the dropdown.

```
def get_result_label(self, result):
    return "{full_name}|{email}" .format(full_name = str(result), email = result.email)
```

If you want it to be a pretty table, you're going to have to delve into dal's javascript.

Comment: Perfect, that is it! I actually tried this but .I guess I had the syntax off as it did seem to work for me :) - Thanks!